# Powershell - Scan DC for new servers + if specific service is running on them

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have script that is scanning my DC for new servers that has been added to my domain + sending an email with the Name, IP and OS of the new server.

What I am looking, is how can i add a line to this script that will check if those new servers has specific Service running on them?

The output that I'm receiving to the email now is:

```
Dear IT Team,
Weekly AD  scan for new servers:

Name    IPv4Address OperatingSystem
test x.x.x.x   Windows Server 2016 Standard
```

So i want somehow to add here a "Service" tab that will say "Servicename" running or no, in those servers.

The script:

```
#>
"Start: "+ (Get-Date)
try
{
$domain=""
if ($domain -eq"")
{
        $domain = Get-ADDomain
}
else
{
        $domain = Get-ADDomain -Identity $domain
}
$domain_name=$domain.name
$distinguished_name = $domain.DistinguishedName
$domain_controller = (Get-ADDomainController -server $domain_name).HostName
$logging_level=1
$search_base = "OU=my-ous," + $distinguished_name
$days_to_search  =-300             # this value needs to be negative integer
if ($days_to_search -ge 0) {throw "Value for variable $days_to_search must be a negative integer in days."}
$date_filter = (get-date).adddays($days_to_search)
$computers=get-adcomputer -SearchBase  $search_base -Properties * -Filter {Created -gt $date_filter -and operatingsystem -like "*windows*"} -server $domain_controller
$computers | Select-Object Name, Created,DistinguishedName,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem | ft -AutoSize

}
Catch
{
    "Error occurred: " + (Get-Date)
    throw
}
$Body = @"
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Dear Team,
            <br/>
            <p>Weekly  scan for new servers:</p>
            $($computers | ConvertTo-Html -Property Name,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem)
            <br/> 
        </body>
    </html>
"@
Send-MailMessage -To "myemail@test.com" -From 'do_not_reply@test.com' -Subject 'New Servers' -Body $Body -SmtpServer 'mysmtp server' -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
```

Comment: Is the `Get-Service` cmdlet what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but where i should add it and how?

Comment: Probably at the end of your try block.  In a foreach loop ( ex - foreach $c in $computers {code to check for service of interest} ) and for the code you'll want something like this to get your services... get-service -computername $c.name | where-object {$_.Name -like '*SQL*'}  probably adding to that  |select name, status at the end to store the results for the service(s) of interest for each computer.  It might be easiest to create a custom ps-object during each iteration to capture the services of interest for that computer, so they can be more easily retrieved when writing your html.